# Adding elements to a page dynamically and then removing them

Tags: jquery

I set up a jQuery control that adds a table containing textboxes to a page dynamically.

The adding part works fine, but the remove function at the end fires no matter where I click in the table...I just want it to remove the table when I click on the remove button.

Is there a better way to set this up?

Thanks

```
    var linkCounter = 1;

    $("#btnAddLink").click(function () {
        if (linkCounter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 learning objectives allowed per page.");
            return false;
        }

      var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'link' + linkCounter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
            '<table>' +
                '<tr><td>' +
                '<label>URL: </label>' +
                '</td><td>' +
                '<input type="text" name="tbLinkUrl" style="width: 300px;"' +
                '" id="tbLinkUrl' + counter + '" value="" >' +
                '</td></tr><tr><td>' +
                '<label>Label: </label>' +
                '</td><td>' +
                '<input type="text" name="tbLinkLabel" style="width: 300px;"' +
                '" id="tbLinkLabel' + counter + '" value="" >' +
                '</td></tr></table>');
           newTextBoxDiv.Append.Html(
              '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeLink">').click(function () {
                  $(this).remove();
                  linkCounter--;
              });
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#linksGroup");
        linkCounter++;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved your remove click event binding outside the addLink event binding. It is now delegated from the body. In my example below the event is delegated to all elements with the class "removeLink". Clicking the button remove it's parent.

I made some small changes to make it work as a demo. The important part is the delegate at the bottom (using on).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hR2hd/)

**Html:**

```
<input id="btnAddLink" value="Click!" type="button" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
var linkCounter = 1;

$("#btnAddLink").click(function () {
    if (linkCounter > 10) {
        alert("Only 10 learning objectives allowed per page.");
        return false;
    }
    var newTextBoxDiv = $("<div>").attr("id", 'link' + linkCounter);
    $(this).after(newTextBoxDiv);
    newTextBoxDiv.html(
        '<table>' +
        '<tr><td>' +
        '<label>URL: </label>' +
        '</td><td>' +
        '<input type="text" name="tbLinkUrl" style="width: 300px;"' +
        '" id="tbLinkUrl' + linkCounter + '" value="" >' +
        '</td></tr><tr><td>' +
        '<label>Label: </label>' +
        '</td><td>' +
        '<input type="text" name="tbLinkLabel" style="width: 300px;"' +
        '" id="tbLinkLabel' + linkCounter + '" value="" >' +
        '</td></tr></table>');
    newTextBoxDiv.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeLink">');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#linksGroup");
    linkCounter++;
});

$('body').on('click','.removeLink',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    linkCounter--;
});
```

Comment: +1 for using delegating events.  I didn't do so in my answer because I just don't have enough practice using it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the click handler like this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.Append.Html(
          '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id='removebutton' value="Remove" class="removeLink">');
$('#removebutton').click(function () {
              $('#mytable').remove();
              linkCounter--;
          });
```

and give your table an id of 'mytable'.

Answer (score 1):

Each function call in jQuery returns a jQuery object, which is why you can string together multiple calls.  But they are all based on the original object:

here:

```
newTextBoxDiv.append.html(
          '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeLink">').click(function () {
              $(this).remove();
              linkCounter--;
          });
```

You are appending an input of type button to the div.  But then you are setting the click event *on the newTextBoxDiv element*, *not* the button.

Create your button, add the click function, then append it:

```
$('&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeLink">')
    .click(function () {
              $(this).siblings('table').remove();
              linkCounter--;
    }).appendTo(newTextBoxDiv);
```

Comment: Note that on the click function `this` references the button.  So you have to find the table to remove, so you can look for the buttons' siblings.  Unless you want to remove the entire div, in which case, use `$(this).parent` instead of `$(this).siblings('table')`